# maybe 'breaks' do not span range of

Tags: r

Did any body know how to solve the following error message: some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'

```
> mydata = read.csv("Income.csv")
> attach(mydata)
> X = Income[!is.na(Income)]#exclude NA value in mydata
> B = seq(floor(min(X)),ceiling(max(X)),by=10)
> hist(X,break=B)
Error in hist.default(X, breaks = B) : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
>str(X)
 num [1:747] 53.92 25.32 0.98 13.12 54.88 ...
```

I have already set the seq() from min(X) to max(X) why there's still error?
BTW, It works when I set by=0.1, but that's not what I want
Help me!!

Comment: `seq(x1, x2, by = dx)` does *not* necessarily span the entire range [x1, x2]. See for example `seq(1, 10, by = 4)`, which gives (1,5,9). You can use `seq(x1, x2, length.out = n)` to make sure that the sequence spans the full range.

Comment: The reason behind this is that `by = x` allows you to specify a *step width*, while `length.out = n` allows you to specify the *number of steps*. See `?seq` for details.

Comment: Btw, I notice you use `attach()`. Probably a habit you should unlearn. It can cause issues like unexpected name conflicts, and it is never necessary. And better alternatives are out there - look into `with`, and be aware of functions that have a `data=` argument. Also packages like data.table and dplyr let you refer to column names in a shorthand way without resorting to attach.

Comment: I used seq(x1, x2, length.out = n) to check, how to know that the sequence spans the full range?

Comment: What do you mean? `breaks <- seq(x1, x2, length.out = n); print(breaks)`? Also, your error message should disappear.

Comment: Btw, the `hist` parameter that let's you define breaks is `breaks = ...` not `break = ...` (as in your example above).

Comment: i mean how to use seq(x1, x2, length.out = n) to make sure that the sequence spans the full range

Comment: As I said, `seq(x1, x2, length.out = n)` where you choose a value for `n` will *by (function) definition* span the entire range [x1, x2]. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Different methods to specify breaks in a histogram.

```
# Generate some data
# Note: I use "ugly" numbers to demonstrate the use of ceiling/floor
set.seed(100);
X <- runif(10000, min = 18720.8, max = 199420.2);

# This will throw an error:
# Error in hist.default(X, breaks = breaks) :
#  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
breaks <- seq(floor(min(X)), ceiling(max(X)), by = 10000);
hist(X, breaks = breaks);

# Either specify the number of breaks directly
hist(X, breaks = 100);

# or specify the number of breaks in your sequence of breaks
breaks <- seq(floor(min(X)), ceiling(max(X)), length.out = 100);
hist(X, breaks = breaks);

# or specify the step width in your sequence of breaks.
# Note: Here you have to make sure that you span the full range of X
breaks <- seq(floor(min(X)), 
              ceiling(max(X)) + ifelse(ceiling(max(X)) %% 10000 != 0, 10000, 0), 
              by = 10000);
hist(X, breaks = breaks);
```

You can see from the last example how the fixed bin width leads to a last bin that is not "full", because it "extends" past the maximum value of X.